# How to add a subview to an ImageView in Android

Tags: android, imageview, subview, addsubview

I come from an iOS background. For some reason, I cannot figure out how to add a view to another view.

I have two `ImageView`s that I am creating programatically as follows:

```
ImageView imageView;
ImageView imageHolder;
```

Now, I want to do something like this:

```
imageHolder.addView(imageView);
```

How do I accomplish this? Did a lot of Googling but no use.

Comment: Could you describe what you're trying to achieve in a more abstract sense? Something like "I want a smaller image placed in the bottom left corner of a larger image" - we could suggest where to look for that; unfortunately adding an ImageView into another ImageView doesn't really make much sense in Android.

Comment: Yeah, its exactly like that. I want to have a bigger image as a background and a smaller image placed ON it as the foreground.

It's pretty straightforward in iOS. But cannot figure out how would I do it in Android

Comment: only ViewGroup and its dubclasses can have child Views added by means of addView

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As pskink said, you can only add views programatically to something that is a [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html). You can add to a `LinearLayout`, for example:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
layout.addView(new EditText(context));
```

That probably won't help your scenario, though. To place an image on top of another you could use a [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html). You'd typically set this up in the XML layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/foregroundImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/backgroundImage"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/backgroundImage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you can specify the images in code if you don't know what they're going to be beforehand:

```
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backgroundImage)).setImageResource(R.drawable.someBackgroundImage);
```

Comment: I would use a RelativeLayout since controlling the relative positions is easier.

Comment: Indeed, sorry if that wasn't clear. You can also add to a RelativeLayout in code if preferred.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks a lot. My concepts are pretty weak when it comes to Android. I did quite a good amount of reading after your post. Now it makes sense. Thanks :)